# How can we access a non-observable dataset from Firebase's Firestore?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

### Background

Most examples of fetching data from Firebase's FireStore via AngularFire:

(a) show the use of `Observable<any[]>` to fetch data:

```
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

(b) to bind it with the template using a pipe to `async`:

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Situation

I don't see examples of how to simply fetch `data: SomeModel[]` and NOT `data: Observable<SomeModel[]>` ... after some struggle, I found a workaround:

```
    async getData(): Promise<SomeModel[]> {
        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.myCollection.snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data.map(e => {
                  return {
                    id: e.payload.doc.id,
                    ...e.payload.doc.data()
                  };
                });
                resolve(this.data);
            });
        });
    }
```

### Question

But as a newcomer to this particular area, my solution feels contrived and I'm looking for how to do this the best way. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Async pipe instead of setting a instance property because async pipe handles unsubscripion upon onDestory. but if you really want to assign the result to property you just assign it in subscribe()

```
 getModel():Observable<MyModel[]>{
         this.myCollection.snapshotChanges().map((data) => {
            return this.data = data.map(e => {
              return {
                id: e.payload.doc.id,
                ...e.payload.doc.data()
              };
            });
        });
    }  

 this.getModel().subscribe(data=>this.data=data)
```